# Reference for the predictability of rigid body dynamics

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, rigid-body-dynamics, chaos-theory, determinism

I'm looking for a reference, journal article, paper, etc. that supports the idea that classical mechanics, in particular rigid body dynamics, is largely [predictable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictability).

A view coming from the background of computer physics simulations would be an added bonus.

Comment: Classical mechanics by definition is predictable. Given a position and momentum, the particle's trajectory can be tracked exactly for all times. I'm confused by what exactly your question is...

Comment: _Classical mechanics by definition is predictable_  I'm looking for a peer reviewed article that confirms this is the case.

Comment: I disagree. I have seen plenty of rigid body mechanisms where minute adjustments in the initial conditions have huge effects in the motion. Since we cannot specify anything with infinite precision chaos will always creep in mechanisms.

Comment: This is good to hear.  It seems that there would be a case for both deterministic and nondeterministic scenarios.  Surely such a topic has been discussed at length in a scholarly publication?

Comment: This really all depends on whether you consider chaotic behavior to be predictable or not. It is well known that classical mechanics is chaotic for suitable systems.

Comment: What are you really interested in?  How classical mechanics is deterministic as a theory but may still be sensitive to numerical errors in measurements/simulations for a given system?  Or how classical mechanics differs from quantum, where even with arbitrary precision, outcomes of measurements are not determined wholly from a previous state?

Comment: _How classical mechanics is deterministic as a theory but may still be sensitive to numerical errors in measurements/simulations for a given system?_  This is what I am looking for, yes.  Written arguments that support this stance.

Comment: Not sure if it qualifies as a reference, but there's a nice discussion on the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy. Had never heard about 'space invaders' before, but it's a cool concept! http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/determinism-causal/ Googling for determinism should get you what you are looking for.

Comment: The references for that article are perfect. Thank you Jaime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the references in Jamie's link I have found a wealth of arguments in the following publication:

*Is Classical Mechanics Really Time-Reversible and Deterministic?*

The full article can be found on JSTOR [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/687650).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on OP's precise definition of [predictability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictability) and [determinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinism), the following fact, taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_Demon), may be relevant:

> *In the history of science, Laplace's demon was the first published articulation of causal or scientific determinism by Pierre-Simon Laplace in 1814.*

Pierre Simon Laplace 1814 article is apparently published in:

> Pierre-Simon Laplace, *A Philosophical Essay on Probabilities* (1902), available [here](http://archive.org/details/philosophicaless00lapliala).